# Setting up primary and secondary dns on one server

Tags: domain-name-system, centos

I'm configuring a vps to be used as webserver, and everything is going well, but now I am coming to the point of DNS. The VPS has two working IP Addresses assigned to it. 
Now I need to get a primary DNS running on one, and a secondary DNS on the other IP Address (I know it is better and safer to run it on two different machines, but that I don't have). 
I can find loads and loads of articles on the iNet on how to configure one DNS on one machine, or two on two different machines, but nothing about how to configure two dns'es on one single machine.
Anyone who can help me?
I'm using Centos 6.3

Comment: Don't do that; use your registrars DNS service it will be much easier for you.

Comment: What's the point in configuring two DNS servers on one server? You're asking more trouble than help with that kind of configuration. If everyone knows you have only one DNS server, then let it be, and tell them to use that IP. Bind etc DNS software does not go down very easily, the event of your VPS going down is much more likely, and when it's down, your DNS is down.

Comment: Don't do this. Just use an external service; even GoDaddy's free DNS service would be better than this.

Comment: Or try [Hurricane Electric](http://he.net)'s free DNS service if you want to avoid companies that degrade women in their advertising. </soapbox>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do what you want easily: Configure your DNS server to listen on both IP addresses.
The internet has no way of knowing whether it's one server or two - it's just happy you have two IP addresses serving your zone's information.

If you do this however you are intentionally disregarding the entire purpose of requiring two DNS servers.

There are plenty of companies out there that provide `free secondary DNS` <--- Google Phrase.
Take the time to understand ***WHY*** we requrie you to have two functioning DNS servers before you go about breaking the internet.

Please also purchase and read [the latest edition of DNS and BIND](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596100575.do) before doing anything else.
This is required reading for anyone who wants to run a DNS server on the internet.

Comment: +1 for *DNS and BIND*. This should be required reading for anyone who is serious about maintaining DNS without a doubt, or for that matter some of those services that make very heavy use of DNS.